# CURL HTTP 302 Error

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I'm writing a web scraper for a project, which needs to login and save some pages, but after even login, saving the `cookie.txt` it redirects back to login page. Looks like it's not logging in.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init(); 
$cookie_file_path = 'cookie.txt'; 
$cookie_file_path = realpath($cookie_file_path); 
$data = array();
$data['txtUser'] = "username";
$data['txtPass'] = "password";

$postStr = "";

foreach($data as $key=>$d){
    $postStr .= $key.'='.urlencode($d).'&';
}

$postStr = substr($postStr,0,-1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
$agent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); 

//new ones 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://madstore.su/login.php"); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postStr);
curl_exec ($ch); // execute the curl command 
echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch); //no errrors 
curl_close ($ch); 
unset($ch); 

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://madstore.su/index.php"); 

//new ones 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 

curl_exec ($ch); 
echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch); 
curl_close ($ch);  

?>
```

I have read about all questions on StackOverflow and searching on Google since hours.

Here is what I'm getting in `cookie.txt`:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

#HttpOnly_.madstore.su  TRUE    /   FALSE   1577145000  __cfduid    d3f365e8218ab84f921e43db0d1500e7c1391327438626
madstore.su FALSE   /   FALSE   0   PHPSESSID   t41g1j9cdl800e9qdj2pq96ef1
```

Here is what I'm getting as curl error:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: cloudflare-nginx
Date: Sun, 02 Feb 2014 08:01:40 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.1.6
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
location: login.php
CF-RAY: f655ad243d007e5-LAX

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: cloudflare-nginx
Date: Sun, 02 Feb 2014 08:01:41 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.1.6
CF-RAY: f655ad5141f07e5-LAX
```

I will highly appreciate if anyone can help me with this issue.

Comment: Related: Use `http_build_query` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to generate URL-encoded POST string.

Comment: What is the response of your first curl request? Insert print of `curl_exec()` returning value to your code

Comment: first response is 200 OK

Comment: I mean the response content returning by `curl_exec()`

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: cloudflare-nginx Date: Sun, 02 Feb 2014 09:52:55 GMT Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Transfer-Encoding: chunked Connection: keep-alive X-Powered-By: PHP/5.1.6 CF-RAY: f65fdc6f5d807df-LAX

Comment: i'm getting right page on first curl_exec()

Comment: If you sure that you getting right page (did you check its content?) on 1st request then most likely the problem is in the path to cookie jar file. Try to replace this snippet `$cookie_file_path = realpath($cookie_file_path);` with the following: `$cookie_file_path = dirname(__FILE__). '/cookie.txt'); `

Comment: still getting same thing bro :(

Comment: this website even showing login page even user logged in, so its also confusing with 1st page content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is wrong. First browse the login page(`http://madstore.su/login.php`) using curl so that it can store the cookies into the file.

Then do the curl posting and use the cookie that saved earlier. Also you are missing this `POST` parameter, so add this with your data.

```
$data['btnLogin'] = "Log in";
```

When the login is done, then browse the required page using your final curl's `GET`.

Comment: thank you so much bro, i was solving since more then 10 hours. thank you soo much !!